# Is it safe to share a SHA-256 hash to check that a sensative number has been copied correctly?

Tags: email, security, encryption, hashing, internet-security

Say I would like to receive a sensitive number from someone (e.g. bank account details). Would it be safe to share the number over the phone and then send an email with the SHA-256 hash of the number to ensure it was copied correctly? I assume it would not be a good idea to say in the email what the number was (because then presumably it would massively narrow down the number of things that map to that hash value).

Comment: Unless one party is hearing impaired or doesn't speak the same language, how hard is it to confirm over the phone someone has written down the correct number?

Comment: _"Would it be safe…"_ - safe against what? Bank account numbers have built in protection against imperfect copying.

Comment: All "Is it safe" questions without further specifications are opinion-based. On one hand you are suggesting a need for error correction codes "copied correctly" on the other hand your are making statements that point to manipulations " (because then presumably it would massively narrow down the number of things that map to that hash value)." As there are hashes and other means to reach each of your assumed goals you should not beat around the bush. Please specify your problem!

Comment: `share the number over the phone` This part doesn't sound particularly "safe" anyway if you are some kind of "security paranoia". I don't see how much "harm" a hash can additionally do. (I mean, why would you assume your (both sides) phones are more secure than your email accounts?)

Comment: "*Closed. This question is opinion-based.*", This question would be correctly answered on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) where people have the required mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @maxbear123 - SHA-256 (SHA-2) is a one way hash.  Once a blob of data is hashed with SHA-2, you cannot reverse the hash output, to determine the original blob of data.  This is the reason SHA-2 can be used as a checksum of a file, the input to SHA-2 is identical, in the case of comparing a checksum of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because then presumably it would massively narrow down the number of things that map to that hash value

This already implies that the original number (e.g. account details) has not enough entropy, and you should not rely on somebody not knowing these details about the number (security through obscurity).

It will be safer, if you tell the other side the number and additionally some random string (make it long enough to have sufficient entropy), and then send them an email with the SHA-256 of the whole combination, e.g. `<number>.<random-string>` (basically a similar idea like a salt in hashed passwords).

**Update**

> How do you share the random string though?

You share the random string over the phone, together with the number. Do **not** put the random string in the email, that would defeat the purpose.

**Update 2**

After thinking more about this, the random string would need to have an entropy similar to the SHA-256 hash to be effective. In that case, it is easier to just send the hash over the phone (instead of the random string), and eliminate the need for the email altogether. Even simpler, in this case now you don't need a cryptographically secure hash, any simple error correcting code would do (and as others mentioned, bank account numbers usually have some checksum built in anyway, but you can add some more if you need to be even safer against accidental errors).

Comment: How do you share the random string though?

Comment: Over the phone, I updated the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I do wonder if this is an XY question (ie would it not be better to ask a safe way of communicating the number).

The safety of sending a hash of the number depends on the size and randomness of the number.  A hash would allow someone to brute force the number if it is small enough.

Another take though -  you spoke the number over the phone.  How many parties would be privileged to that communication unencrypted - I put you many more then are privy to end-to-end encrypted email.

Someone with the knowledge to check a hash presumably has the knowledge to use PGP or a secure email client or https web page (ie communicate using public key encryption) - surely that would be your answer?  Otherwise something like Signal messenger?

Answer (score -1):

You could try encrypting the email using a password, or try obfuscating it but you would still need a way to tell the other side how to get the original hash back out from the email. Another option would be to use Base64 or some other method to encode the message so a random person doesn't immediately see what was done to the message, but no extra information is required to revert the encoding.

Comment: Base64 is very obvious. 66% of encoded messages end with `=` or `==`, and for the remaining 33% (or if the padding is removed) base64 is the first thing to test for. Security by obscurity shouldn't be the only layer of protection.